# How to fetch serialized data from wordpress options

Tags: plugins, plugin-development, jquery, array, options

I have the following serialized data in a wp option `a:2:{s:5:"Title";s:11:"your title";s:7:"Message";s:20:"Hola testing testing";}`

I would like to return it to be used in a form, and show it also in the front end, I tried

```
<?php echo get_option('notice_data[Message]'); ?>
```

this is the array

```
$notice_data = array(
    'Title' => '',
    'Message' => ''
);
add_option("notice_data", 'Default', '', 'yes');
```

I am creating a plugin that have a settings page with two forms that save the data in the wp option in order to be used by the jquery function inside a js file, here is part of the settings page;

```
<textarea name="notice_data[Title]" id="notice_data" />
<?php echo get_option('notice_data[Title]'); ?>
</textarea>
</td>
</tr>
<tr valign="top">
<th width="92" scope="row">Body Message</th>
<td width="406">
<textarea name="notice_data[Message]" id="notice_data" cols="40" rows="10" />
<?php echo get_option('notice_data[Message]'); ?>
</textarea>
```

I am also localizing the script to fetch the data saved in the wp option to be used inside a jquery function that shows the messages when certain conditions are met, so how do I fetch the serialized data?

Comment: _"But it wont work"_ ... is ***no*** proper Error description. :)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

No, this won't work:

```
<?php echo get_option('notice_data[Message]'); ?>
```

Because [`get_option`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_option) pulls whole option value by `option_name`, it doesn't pull by pieces of the serialized array. What you are asking for is a key (`option_name`) called literally `notice_data[Message]`. Assuming you've saved the option as `notice_data` you aren't going to get a match, and I am not even sure if brackets are supported in the option name. I've never tried.

What you need is...

```
$notice_data = get_option('notice_data');
echo $notice_data['Message'];
```

You said that you are "localizing the script". so for use by jQuery/Javascript you'd do something like this ([almost completely cribbed from the Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_localize_script#Example)):

```
$notice_data = get_option('notice_data');

wp_enqueue_script( 'some_handle' );
$translation_array = array( 
    'notice_data' => $notice_data['Message'] 
);
wp_localize_script( 'some_handle', 'object_name', $translation_array );
```

Your Javascript should have access to it as `object_name.notice_data`.

Comment: but how do you show it in jQuery, I am using something like `+ notice_data +`

Comment: it isnt working for me mate, it returns null, but when i dump the array, the data is in there, no idea what the problem is

Comment: What _exactly_ returns `null`? Where do you dump the data?

Comment: localizing returns null `/* <![CDATA[ */
var lu_ban_object = {"title":null,"msg":null};
/* ]]> */
</script>`